# ¿Porqué la instancia de mi calendario no se corresponde con la hora actual del teléfono?

Tags: android

Buenas, tengo un código en el cual comparo la hora actual con una hora elegida por un `TimePickerDialog`, el problema es que la instancia que hago del calendario para saber la hora actual me da una hora incorrecta, es decir, con respecto a la hora del dispositivo me da una hora siempre de -2 (dos horas menos). Espero que me puedan ayudar, les dejo aquí el código y los Log que he hecho para comprobar esto.

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
final Calendar fEle = Calendar.getInstance();

        final ArrayList total = new ArrayList();


       ............................
       //Codigo de un dialogo de calendario que no tiene que ver con esto

                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener otsl = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {

                        fEle.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,i);
                        fEle.set(Calendar.MINUTE,i1);


                        if (cal.isEquivalentTo(hEle)) {
                            int horaActual=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minActual=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                            boolean bHora=false;
                            boolean bMin=false;
                            boolean igual=false;

                            Log.v("horas","Hora actual: "+horaActual);
                            Log.v("horas","Hora actual1 : "+i);
                            Log.v("horas","Hora actual2: "+fEle.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                            Log.v("horas","min actual : "+minActual);
                            Log.v("horas","min actual1 : "+i1);
                            Log.v("horas","min actual2 : "+fEle.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                            if(horaActual==i)
                                igual=true;
                            if(horaActual>fEle.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                                bHora=true;
                            if(minActual>=fEle.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                                bMin=true;
```

> 10-16 17:30:31.022 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: Hora actual: 15
>
> 10-16 17:30:31.022 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: Hora actual1 : 23
>
> 10-16 17:30:31.023 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: Hora actual2: 23
>
> 10-16 17:30:31.023 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: min actual : 30
>
> 10-16 17:30:31.023 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: min actual1 : 25
>
> 10-16 17:30:31.023 3888-3888/es.aandg.demo V/horas: min actual2 : 25

Como se puede ver, la hora actual son las 17:30, sin embargo en la instancia del calendario es de 2 horas menos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este caso **debes definir una zona horaria para obtener correctamente la hora**, por ejemplo si te encuentras en Madrid, España puedes definir como TimeZone `"Europe/Madrid"`:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 timeformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
 Log.v("horas", "La hora es : " + timeformat.format(cal.getTime())
```

De acuerdo a tu código se realizaría de esta forma:

```
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
        int horaActual = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minActual = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        Log.v("horas", "Hora actual: " + horaActual);
        Log.v("horas", "min actual : " + minActual);
```

Agrego una [lista de TimeZones](https://gist.github.com/dumbfingers/4042685) usadas en Android.

Comment: Porque razón -1 ? sería bueno para definir si existe algún error en mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo, ese era el fallo. Un saludo

Comment: @AdriánGarridoBlázquez excelente Adrián, saludos.